# Java util Timer - Thread addition

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, daemon

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

// scheduling the task at interval
timer.schedule(tasknew,100, 100);
```

If this is added as part of a web-application at the startup, how is the task getting kicked off at the scheduled time? Is a new daemon thread process being created, solely for triggering this task?

I just want to understand if we are creating any additional thread that is responsible for this task threads?

Comment: Yes you are creating another thread.

Comment: Note that "thread" and "process" are different things - "daemon thread process" is not a meaningful term.

Answer (score 1):

> I just wanted to understand if we are creating any additional threads that is responsible for this task threads?

Yes - from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html):

> Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially.